# Android getIdentifier returns 0x1?

Tags: android, android-resources

On a small set of devices running my application users are getting a crash when changing an image via preferences. Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.printandpixel.lolhistory/com.printandpixel.lolhistory.activities.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3346)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2329)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1846)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1814)
    at com.printandpixel.lolhistory.util.GeneralUtils.getDrawableFromName(GeneralUtils.java:226)
    at com.printandpixel.lolhistory.util.GeneralUtils.getHomepageHeader(GeneralUtils.java:277)
    at com.printandpixel.lolhistory.activities.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:252)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1255)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3335)
    ... 11 more
```

The line in function getDrawableFromName that is being referred to here is the following:

`return context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);`

The full implementation of this method is as follows:

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromName(String name, Context context) {
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
    } else {
        Tracker t = ((LoLHistory) ((Activity) context).getApplication()).getTracker(LoLHistory.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory("EVENT").setAction("DrawableNotFound").setLabel(name).build());
        return null;
    }
}
```

<s>From what I can tell this so far is happening only on Android 5 and not on all Android 5 devices.</s> As far as I can tell the documentation specifies that `getIdentifier` should return 0 if the drawable isn't found but in this case it returns 0x1? There are hundreds of different images in my application and all the user reports have 0x1 as the invalid id.

Is it safe to assume that resourcesIds of 1 are all invalid?

**Edit:** As per @ρяσѕρєяK suggestion, to handle the deprecation of getDrawable(id), and to fail gracefully when resources are unexpectedly not found I have edited my function to be as follows:

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromName(String name, Context context) {
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    Drawable drawable = null;
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId, context.getTheme());
        } else {
            drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Tracker t = ((LoLHistory) ((Activity) context).getApplication()).getTracker(LoLHistory.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory("EVENT").setAction("DrawableNotFound").setLabel(name).build());
    }
    return drawable;
}
```

Comment: `getDrawable ` method is deprecated `in API level 22` so try it using `getDrawable(int, Theme)` on greater version of level 22.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thanks for the tip. I have updated my get drawable method to work around the deprecation and fail gracefully. See edit in question.

Comment: @alexgophermix You can also make use of `ContextCompat.getDrawable (Context context, int id)` from support library.

Comment: @b1izzard ah this would basically replace the need for the if else in the amendment. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up not being due to the `getDrawableFromName` function. It was actually completely unrelated :(. I  had another function in my app to get a specific default preference value as follows:

```
public static Drawable getHomepageHeader(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String headerImageName = prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_champion_header_name), "darius_600");
    Drawable drawable = getDrawableFromName(headerImageName, context);
    if (drawable == null) {
        drawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green));
    }
    return drawable;
}
```

This preference was set in a `PreferenceActivity` with the following `ListPreference`:

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="pref_champion_header"
    android:entries="@array/headers"
    android:entryValues="@array/header_values"
    android:summary="Champion splash to appear at the top of the homepage"
    android:title="Homepage champion"
    android:defaultValue="1"/>
```

With the following two arrays being referenced:

```
<string-array name="headers" translatable="false">
    <item>Darius</item>
    <item>Garen</item>
    <item>Malphite</item>
    <item>Gnar</item>
    <item>Buccaneer Tristana</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="header_values" translatable="false">
    <item>darius_600</item>
    <item>garen_600</item>
    <item>malphite_600</item>
    <item>gnar_600</item>
    <item>buccaneer_tristana_600</item>
</string-array>
```

For whatever reason on some devices `defaultValue="1"` resolved to the first entry of `header_values` and on others it simply resolved to `"1"` which resulted to `"1"` being passed to my custom `getDrawableFromName` method. To fix this I simply changed `defaultValue` to explicitly equal the first value of the header_values array aka `"darius_600"`